# What is the best way to represent a constrained many-to-many relationship within a relational database?

Tags: database, relationship

I would like to establish a many-to-many relationship with a constraint that only one or no entity from each side of the relationship can be linked at any one time.

A good analogy to the problem is cars and parking garage spaces. There are many cars and many spaces. A space can contain one car or be empty; a car can only be in one space at a time, or no space (not parked).

We have a Cars table and a Spaces table (and possibly a linking table). Each row in the cars table represents a unique instance of a car (with license, owner, model, etc.) and each row in the Spaces table represents a unique parking space (with address of garage floor level, row and number). What is the best way to link these tables in the database and enforce the constraint describe above?

(I am using C#, NHibernate and Oracle.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not worried about history - ie only worried about "now", do this:

```
create table parking (
  car_id references car,
  space_id references space,
  unique car_id,
  unique space_id
);
```

By making both car and space references unique, you restrict each side to a maximum of one link - ie a car can be parked in at most one space, and a space can has at most one car parked in it.

Comment: This makes sense - the unique constraint on each of the foreign keys would enforce the constraint I am after.

Answer (score 1):

in any relational database, many to many relationships must have a join table to represent the combinations. As provided in the answer (but without much of the theoretical background), you cannot represent a many to many relationship without having a table in the middle to store all the combinations.

It was also mentioned in the solution that it only solves your problem if you don't need history. Trust me when I tell you that real world applications almost always need to represent historical data. There are many ways to do this, but a simple method might be to create what's called a ternary relationship with an additional table. You could, in theory, create a "time" table that also links its primary key (say a distinct timestamp) with the inherited keys of the other two source tables. this would enable you to prevent errors where two cars are located in the same parking spot during the same time. using a time table can allow you the ability to re-use the same time data for multiple parking spots using a simple integer id.

So, your data tables might look like so

table car
car_id (integers/numbers are fastest to index)
...

table parking-space 
space_id
location

table timeslot
time_id integer
begin_datetime (don't use seconds unless you must!)
end_time (don't use seconds unless you must!)

now, here's where it gets fun. You add the middle table with a composite primary key that is made up of car.car_id + parking_space.space_id + time_id. There are other things you could add to optimize here, but you get the idea, I hope.

table reservation
car_id PK
parking_space_id PK
time_id PK (it's an integer - just try to keep it as highly granular as possible - 30 minute increments or something - if you allow this to include seconds / milliseconds /etc the advantages are cancelled out because you can't re-use the same value from the time table)
(this would also be the place to store variable rates, discounts, etc distinct to this particular account, reservation, etc).

now, you can reduce the amount of data because you aren't replicating the timestamp in the join table (reservation). By using an integer, you can re-use that timeslot for multiple parking spaces, but you could also apply a constraint preventing two cars from renting that given spot for the same "timeslot" for a given day / timeframe. This would also make it easier to store some history about the customers - who knows, you might want to see reports on customers who rent more often and offer them discounts or something.

By using the ternary relationship model, you are making each spot unique to a given timeslot (perhaps with some added validation rules), so the system can only store one car in one parking spot for one given time period.

By using integers as keys instead of timestamps, you are assured that the database won't need to do any heavy lifting to index the keys and sort / query against. This is a common practice in data warehousing / OLAP reporting when you have massive datasets and you need efficiency. I think it applies here as well.

Answer (score 0):

create a third table.

```
parking
--------
car_id
space_id
start_dt
end_dt
```

for the constraint, i guess the problem with your situation is that you need to check a complex rule against the intersection table itself.  if you try this in a trigger, it will report a mutation.

one way to avoid this would be to replicate the table, and query against this replication for the constraint.

Comment: Thanks, I was leaning towards a linking table. Not sure I understand how replication applies, though. How would this enforce the constraint? Also, I am not concerned about the time in my scenario - just the present state of the garage.